# How to create a div that behaves exactly like its clone but doesnt get affected by the events on it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on creating a div that bounces when it encounters a wall and clones itself when clicked on it. I've come up with the following code. It works all fine but after multiple clicks, many divs are formed and when ever one of the div encounters a wall, all the divs are bouncing. Kindly help on how I can solve this problem.

Bouncing Div

```
<style>
div.bound {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style:solid;
    width:462px;
    height:302px;
    border-width:1px
}
div.move {
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>

<script language="javascript">
var x = 5; //Starting x coord.
var y = 5; //Starting y coord.
var max_x = window.innerWidth; //maximum x coord.
var max_y = window.innerHeight; //maximum y coord.
var xoffset = 10; //Move 10px every step
var yoffset = 10; //Move 10px every step
var TimeID;

function duplicate() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    var divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true);

    document.body.appendChild(divClone);
}

function moveLogo() {
    x = x + xoffset;
    y = y + yoffset;


    var yarray = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
    for (var i = 0; i < yarray.length; i++) {

        yarray[i].style.top = y - (i * 50) + 'px';
        if ((y - (i * 50) + yoffset > max_y - 25) || (y - (i * 50) + yoffset < 0)) yoffset *= -1;

    }
    var xarray = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
    for (var j = 0; j < xarray.length; j++) {

        xarray[j].style.left = x - (j * 50) + 'px';
        if ((x - (j * 50) + xoffset > max_x - 25) || (x - (j * 50) + xoffset < 0)) xoffset *= -1;
    }


    TimeID = window.setTimeout('moveLogo()', 100);


}
</script>
```

```
<div id="myDiv" class="move" onclick="duplicate()">
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the onclick event from all the duplicates... add this in your duplicate function `divClone.removeAttribute("onclick");`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kWn83/

Comment: Correct me, but when you duplicate a DIV, doesn't the id get cloned as well? Try using event.target instead of getElementById("myDiv").

Comment: ID is unique so it can't be cloned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using only one set of `xoffset` and `yoffset` variables for all elements. You need one set of them for each element, so that each element can have its own direction.

You can for example use arrays, so that each element has one item in each array.

(Also, you can use an array to keep references to the elements, so that you don't have to use `getElementByClassName` over and over.)

Comment: Oh ok. I think I got my mistake. Will try your suggestion. Thank you!